# What is Security.allowDomain("*")

Tags: flash, security, cross-domain

i am new to security related issues. i got new requirement like "**Thread – Security.allowDomain("*") is used in a Flash movie."**.

I have searched for security.allowdomain("*") in Visual Studio 2008. but did not get any keyword.

Please tell me. what it is exactly.

Comment: Is this actually related to ASP.Net? All resources I have found point to flex or flash. Are you incorporating a flash or flex application into your web page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Security.allowDomain() allows a file lodem from a different domain access scripts in the original file. For example I load a file from www.domainB.com to file under www.domainA.com, you need to allow www.domainB.com to access your data.

For example the YouTube AS3 player class works this way.

The XML definition of allowed domains in crossdomain.xml allows to load files from your server to different domains.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable Answers. I understood concept now... After i made this changes, how i can test weather i did correct or not.

Comment: Load an SWF that tries to call a function from the the file that loaded it.